# Is there a method to speed up Android App Building?

Tags: android, compiler-construction

After having a few additional libraries to my android app it takes about 45 seconds to build. I am on a QuadCore 2.3 GHz Linux PC. Is there something I can do to speed up the building, like muti threaded building?

Comment: How often do you have to build your app? Is 45 seconds so terrible? If you don't want to build automatically every time you save a code item then just turn Build Automatically off.

Comment: Are you building with Eclipse, Ant, Maven?  My Linux box isn't near that fast, but compiles rather quickly.

Comment: With Eclipse ADT, I do often make changes to see quick results. It compiles very fast if I am not using Admob SDK and Flurry SDK in my app

Comment: Not an issue anymore, after switching to Ubuntu my build takes a few seconds even with the external libraries